# Create sub tag by XML::Simple in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, perl-module

I am using `XML::Simple` to create xml from hash ,i want to add on more sub tag after the MainRoot in my XML .This is my hash

```
my $args= {
            'KEY1' => "Value1",
            'KEY2' => "Value2",
            'KEY3' => "Value3",
            'KEY4' => "Value4",
            'KEY5' => "Value5",
            'KEY6' => "Value6",
    };


XML::Simple Code

print XMLout($args,NoAttr => 1,RootName => 'MainRoot');
```

**Out Put**

```
<MainRoot>
  <KEY1>Value1</KEY1>
  <KEY2>Value2</KEY2>
  <KEY3>Value3</KEY3>
  <KEY4>Value4</KEY4>
  <KEY5>Value5</KEY5>
  <KEY6>Value6</KEY6>
</MainRoot>
```

**Desired**

```
<MainRoot>
    <SubTag>
      <KEY1>Value1</KEY1>
      <KEY2>Value2</KEY2>
      <KEY3>Value3</KEY3>
      <KEY4>Value4</KEY4>
      <KEY5>Value5</KEY5>
      <KEY6>Value6</KEY6>
     </SubTag>
</MainRoot>
```

How can we do this by XML::Simple .Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can just add another key and hash:

```
my $args= {
           'SubTag' => {
            'KEY1' => "Value1",
            'KEY2' => "Value2",
            'KEY3' => "Value3",
            'KEY4' => "Value4",
            'KEY5' => "Value5",
            'KEY6' => "Value6",
          },
    };
```

Output:

```
<MainRoot>
  <SubTag>
    <KEY1>Value1</KEY1>
    <KEY2>Value2</KEY2>
    <KEY3>Value3</KEY3>
    <KEY4>Value4</KEY4>
    <KEY5>Value5</KEY5>
    <KEY6>Value6</KEY6>
  </SubTag>
</MainRoot>
```